# convert date mm/dd/yyyy to mm.dd.yyyy word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have  the  following dates

2/12/2018
2/13/2018
2/14/2018

I need to convert the above dates into 12.2.2018,13.2.2018,14.2.2018  and these dates  should be  underline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will insert the date in the desired format to the cursor position and inserts a trailing space, too.

```
Dim d As String

d = "7/25/2011"
With Selection
    .Font.Underline = wdNone            ' next text will not be underlined
    .TypeText " "                       ' or any separator that will follow the date
    .Collapse                           ' remove selection
    .Start = .Start - 1                 ' set cursor before the separator
    .Collapse                           ' remove selection
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle ' next text will be underlined
    .TypeText Format(d, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    .Collapse                ' remove selection and leave the cursor right after the date
End With
```

Comment: You don't even need a macro for this - it can be done for all dates via a single *wildcard* Find/Replace without the need to select anything...